# How to work vue i18n pluralization?

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

I have locale messages the below:

```
timing: {
  viewer: {
    count: 'нету таймингов | 1 тайминг | 2 тайминга | 3 тайминга | 4 тайминга | {count} таймингов'
  }
}
```

My template the below:

```
<span>{{ $tc('timing.viewer.count', 50, {count: 50}) }}</span>
```

Output the below:

```
<span>2 тайминга</span>
```

Why?? tag span must have "50 таймингов"

Comment: Looks like a bug, pluralize translation string doesn't support more than 3 arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is wrong.

Try it like this

```
timing: {
 viewer: {
   count: 'нету таймингов | 1 тайминг | {count} таймингов'
  }
}
```

When using the count version of **$tc** i18n will look at the 3rd argument in the template.

Comment: But do not forget that the Slavic languages are more difficult with pluralization and you need a custom function 
In this case, you forgot to consider these values:
2 тайминга | 3 тайминга | 4 тайминга